# Positioning text bottom and centering at the same time

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to position a nav element in a coloured box. The text in this box should be on the bottom and center of this box.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sixteen columns">
  <section id="mainNav">
    <ul>
      <li id="nav2" class="navitem"><a href="#">ux / ui</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div><!--end sixteen columns-->
```

**CSS:**

```css
    /*navigation styles*/
 .sixteen.columns #mainNav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#mainNav .navitem {
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    pointer: cursor;
}
#mainNav ul li a {
    font-family: print_clearlyregular, "Arial", serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
}
#mainNav #nav2 {
    background: rgb(3, 106, 113);
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
    margin-right: 4px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

As soon as I  absolute position the "ul li a", the text-align: center doesn't work. How should I fix that?

You can see this bit in jsfiddle as well:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juhant/YfmCR/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `width:100%;` to

`#mainNav ul li a {}`

the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/bcM2x/

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify any value for `left` (or `right` for that matter) for `ul li a`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add an alternative solution that doesn't rely on floats or absolute positioning, which can get pretty messy.

Using `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, and `vertical-align: bottom`, you can achieve said result.  This also scales well when other items around it may change.

### [*Here is a working jsFiddle demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/2HjGe/)

[image: jsFiddle demo screenshot]

---

### CSS Changes

*I removed all float and position styles, added `display: table` to the `ul`, added `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom` to the `li`, added `display: inline-block` to the `a` along with `margin-bottom: 15px` to retain that padding your absolute positioning created.  I modified the selectors and added a few other minor things that you can use or adjust to your liking.*

```
/*navigation styles*/
#mainNav 
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#mainNav > ul 
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
#mainNav > ul > li 
{   
    display: table-cell;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    pointer: cursor;
    background: rgb(3, 106, 113);
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
    margin-right: 4px;
}

#mainNav > ul > li > a
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: print_clearlyregular, "Arial", serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    background: blue; // added for demo to show width and margin
}
```